# Difference between /views and /lib folders?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm creating a Express/React app and I'm trying to understand the basic scaffolding structure.

In my root I have `app.js` which starts everything when I run `npm run dev`, which calls the script:

`"dev": "pm2 start app.js --watch --interpreter ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node"`, which is equivalent to `node app.js` as far as I can tell.

In my `app.js` I've set `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');`, meaning whenever an `app.get(...)` is called, express will look inside the `/views` folder for the specified file.

However, I also have a `/lib` folder which I've seen many other project have. I'll eventually be making components inside `/lib/components`.

Does that mean that the templates I have inside `/views` will `require` or `import` components from `/lib/components`? Why not just keep all my `*.jsx` files inside one folder? Or is `/views` just meant for top level templates..?

Answer (score 0):

`lib` is used to create style-component libraries. Since you know React, you probably know about Javascript frameworks, think of this one as a CSS or a SASS framework. When you create a javascript library, you need to import it to use it, this is what the lib directory does.

From the styled-component explanation, taken off [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components).

> Styled-components allows you to write actual CSS code to style your
>   components. It also removes the mapping between components and styles
>   – using components as a low-level styling construct could not be
>   easier!

You probably know how to use React, but to see more on how to create components with react please see [this link](https://hackernoon.com/building-a-react-component-library-part-1-d8a1e248fe6c)